# SharePoint date-picker picking up next date instead of today

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, datepicker

I'm having problem with date-picker. The current system date is 8/30/2016, time is 11:19 pm. but in the time section it's picking up next date (8/31 instead of 8/30) see screenshot below.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: May be its time zone issues. Check time zones for server and for sharepoint - from regional settings

Comment: I checked that system time zone and SharePoint time zone are same.

Answer (score 2):

- Frist make sure that the windows data is set correctly .
- Go to site Settings > Site Administion > Regional Settings. and adjust it as the following based on your Time zone that selected for Windows.

[image]

Note : in some calendar type like Hijri you can set +1 or 1